# How to replace while with a recursive function?

Tags: javascript, recursion, while-loop

I'm using `while` in this fashion:

```
while (value < -180 || value > 180) {
  if (value < -180) {
    value += 360
  }
  if (value > 180) {
    value -= 360
  }
}
```

I would like, though, to use a recursive function instead of `while`. I searched on Google but couldn't [find](https://www.google.com.tw/search?rlz=1C1ASUC_enTW628TW628&q=javascript%20while%20recursive%20function&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjTlbGnu7zVAhVLHZQKHanpAPUQvwUIISgA&biw=1745&bih=935) anything. So I thought maybe I could get the answer here.

Comment: Why use recursion? Unless the problem specifically benefits from a recursive solution, recursion can hinder your program.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I want to avoid using `while` for personal reasons.

Comment: I would encourage you to consider those personal reasons carefully. Every tool has its place.

Comment: How could `if (value < -180)` be `true` if `while (value < -180 || value > 180)` is `true`? What is input and expected result?

Comment: @Carcigenicate it's good to learn new things for their own sake. When the time comes, it might be handy for Alex to know how to do it with recursion.

Comment: @user151841 I agree learning recursion is important, and if this is purely an exercise, then that's good. I was just cautioning against using recursion just for the sake of using it.

Comment: Alex, as aptly pointed out by @Carcigenicate , recursion can hinder your program. In general, recursion that isn't optimized away by the interpreter/compiler (isn't converted into a `while` loop) is usually more expensive, slower and includes an inherent stack overflow risk. It's good that you're learning about recursion, but you should also learn about it's risks and limitations.

Comment: This seems like a really small, low-stakes situation. In other words, a perfect place to try out something new, just beyond your horizon. OP clearly is capable of replacing the recursion with a while loop. How else are you really going to learn it, without actually creating it and playing around with it? You don't learn if you think everyting must be done perfectly correct the first time. Play, try new things, make mistakes, get familiar with it, learn. That's the only way.

Comment: @user151841 I don't think anyone's arguing that. I felt the need to caution against recursion because it's not rare for me to see people trying to force recursion in situations where is doesn't make sense. I have to loosely paraphrase Myst that learning a new technique is great, but you must also learn the limitations as well to truly benefit from it. I felt it was important to point that out. Given I use recursion daily while writing Clojure, I'm certainly not discrediting it.

Comment: If you don't know a tool, you don't know it's place. You can read all the book you want, but until you've used it, used it wrong, wrote it and re-wrote it, you can't really say you know it. There's no way to learn coding but to code. You can't start out doing it right the first time, so make as many low-stakes mistakes as you can

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "general formula" for converting an explicit loop to a recursive solution is:

- Figure out what the "accumulators" of the loop are. Often, the loop will be manipulating one or two values, and those values are the "result" of the loop.
- Make the accumulators the parameters of a function.

It's difficult to generalize how any old loop can be replaced with recursion, but this can be used as a general guideline:

For a loop with the form:

```
var a, b, c = ...;

while (condition) {
   // Change a, b, c...
}

// Use a, b, c
```

You can convert that to:

```
function recursive(a, b, c...) {
   // When the condition does *not* hold, end the recursion.
   // Note that condition is negated relative to the while-loop.
   if (!condition) {
      // Base case.
      return [a, b, c...];

   } else {
      // Change a, b, c...
      //  and recurse with the new values
      return recursive(a', b', c'...);
   }
}
```

For your example, this would look something like:

```
function recur(value) {
  if (value > -180 || value < 180) {
    return value; // Base case

  } else if (value < -180) {
    return recur(value + 360);

  } else {
    return recur(value - 360);
  }
}
```

In cases where you expect to loop again, recurse, *but remember that you need to return the result of the recursion*. For cases where you want to end the loop, return the accumulator. Note that every branch of execution *must end in a return*. As soon as you discard the result of a recurse (by not returning it), the data is lost.

Note though:

- As I mentioned in the comments, recursion isn't a hammer that should be thrown at just any old problem; especially when the language isn't optimized for it. It may be fine for small problems, but down the road, you may find it will suddenly start causing StackOverflows out of nowhere when the problem becomes bigger.
- Recursion can become difficult and confusing when dealing with *mutable* data. If your accumulators are *mutable* (a list, map, or any other non-primitive), you must be very careful with how you set everything up. The same data will be able to be accessed *and changed* from every branch of the recursion. If you aren't careful, you'll have your accumulators being changed out from under you in very hard-to-debug ways. If you want to go the recursive/functional path, I'd encourage you to look into a library like Immutable.js, or a language like Clojurescript that deals almost exclusively with immutable structures. Clojurescript compiles into JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the example. But I would like a recursive function that can be applied to any situation where while could be used. Not just my example.

Comment: @alex Recursion is hard to generalize like that; that's why I include that list at the start of the answer. I'll try to write up a generalized "blueprint" though.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
var recur_num = recursion(500)
console.log(recur_num)

var while_num = viaLoop(500)
console.log(while_num)

function recursion(value) {
  
  if (value < -180) {
    return recursion(value + 360);
 } 
  
  if(value > 180){
    return recursion(value - 360);
  }
  
   if (value > -180 || value < 180) {
    return value; 
  }
}


function viaLoop(value){

while (value < -180 || value > 180) {

 if (value < -180) {
    value += 360
  }
   
  if (value > 180) {
    value -= 360
  }
}

return value;
}
```

You can compare both the recursion version value and the while loop version value

Comment: Let me know if you have any concern?